# How do I use docker-compose.debug.yml to debug my node running in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have used [vs docker extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PeterJausovec.vscode-docker) to create docker files. But I don't know what is the "proper" way to use docker-compose.debug.yml to debug my code, e.g. how do I set my env. so I can just hit F5 and all the magic happen.

I did work out a way to debug my code. First run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.debug.yml` in terminal. Then use the launch.json from [In-container Node Development: Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/developer-tools/nodejs-debugging/VSCode-README.md) to attach to my node in docker.

But I think Code may provide a simpler way to streamline the debug process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that but through some modifications.

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Remote",
            "address": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 9229,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
            "preLaunchTask": "start_node_compose"
        }
        // {
        //     "type": "node",
        //     "request": "launch",
        //     "name": "Launch Program",
        //     "program": "${workspaceRoot}/index.js"
        // }
    ]
}
```

As you can see I commented the local launch and made this the first one so it is run on F5. Next we need to define a `start_node_compose` task

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "myCommand",
    "isShellCommand": false,
    "args": [],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "start_node_compose",
            "showOutput": "always",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "command": "/bin/bash",
            "args": [
                "-c",
                "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.debug.yml up -d && sleep 10"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Then when you run the command using F5 you will be able to hit the breakpoint

[image: Debug Breakpoint]

Comment: Hi, if my docker-compose.yml has more than one services I don't know how to attach debugger the node service, how to set remoteRoot? Is it possible to do that? I raised an issue here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/issues/29

Comment: If you have more services, you will still have one node process or more? If there is just one node process then this would work

Comment: Hi, I have updated my comment at github. I did have one node, but I don't know how to make it work. Can you show me how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Just change `remoteRoot` to `/app` in my config and it should work for you

Comment: Hi, I actually tried that but it didn't work. Same error message "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229".

Comment: Please follow the docs properly : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387. it will save you a ton of time!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Using `--inspect=0.0.0.0:9229` solved it.
I recommend you use `--inspect-brk` too, to have the node process wait for the debugger to attach.