# Emacs - Is it possible to debug multi containers (docker-compose)?

Tags: debugging, docker, emacs, docker-compose, emacs24

I've found some information regarding debugging Node applications using:

Webstorm: https://medium.com/@creynders/debugging-node-apps-in-docker-containers-through-webstorm-ae3f8efe554d

Vscode: [How do I use docker-compose.debug.yml to debug my node running in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46500639/how-do-i-use-docker-compose-debug-yml-to-debug-my-node-running-in-docker)

I'm struggling to find any solution when it comes to Emacs, I know there are some plugins like "https://github.com/realgud/realgud" but AFAIK it wasn't made to work with containers

Any thoughts about it?

Thanks!! :)